# Do I need to wrap `new Object()` when using Polymer default property function?

Tags: javascript, polymer

The [Polymer 1.0 documentation states](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#default-values),

> If the default value should be an array or object unique to the instance, create the array or object inside a function.

Do I need to wrap object constructors such as `new Thing(params)` in an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the library doesn't make an effort in deciding whether the property's value should be value-copied when it's an object reference.

The basics are in javascript:

```
var C = function() {
}
C.prototype.property = {};
var a = new C();
var b = new C();
a.property.value = "Hello world"
console.log(b.property); // object { "value": "Hello world" }
```

both `a` and `b` share a reference to the same object reference. As opposed to:

```
var C = function() {
    this.property = {};
}
var a = new C();
var b = new C();
a.property.value = "Hello world"
console.log(b.property); // empty object
```

A new object reference is created each time the object is instantiated. This is always something to be aware of when working with objects in javascript. And arrays are in fact objects, so they play by the same rules.

Comment: So this has to do with avoiding accidentally adding properties on the prototype chain?  Perhaps you could comment on whether it would be safe to (for example) define a `new Map()` object – that should be safe since you interact with it via a clearly defined API, right?

Comment: I am using the prototype as an example, but it's basically the same principle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that part of the documentation is referring to [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values)

> The value may either be a primitive value, or a function that returns a value (which should be used for initializing Objects and Arrays to avoid shared objects on instances).

In this example, a property called `data` is being declared which is an `Object`. The value for this property is calling `function` which is returns a new `Object`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is idiomatic and simpler.